# JavaScript object as array

Tags: javascript, associative-array, javascript-objects

Accessing Js object properties :

What is the difference between :

```
1) Obj.src
     vs
2) Obj["src"]
```

I only know that  #1 can't be used with number ( e.g. if the property name is "1")

Is there any other major differences ?

Comment: @Dennis well , sort of duplicate. I didnt see the remark that dot notation **can't** be used with number. ( very important)

Comment: You're right, my bad.  I assumed a link titled "characters that can't be used with dot notation" would include a list of characters that can't be used with dot notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference really. Old'ish browser showed some performance differences using either the one or the other notation, but those times are over.

The only important difference is that the bracket notation is your only chance to *dynamically* access Object properties.

For instance:

```
var access = 'src';

Obj[ access ];
```

you can't do that using a dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, **every object is an [associative array](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)**.

I can't think of much more to add besides its one of the <strike>better</strike> magical features of JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `Obj.src` and `Obj["src"]`.

But when the property name is a variable, you could only use the second way to access it.

```
var name = "src";
```

Then you need to use `Obj[name]`, `Obj.name` will try to access the property with the name of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

The set of properties that can be accessed with bracket notation is a superset of the properties that can be accessed with dot notation.  Anything accessed with the dot must be a [valid JavaScript identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

> a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number.

Properties can still be strings that are not identifiers, but require bracket notation for access:

```
object["I have whitespace"];
object["1startswithanumber"];
object["Punctuation!!??"];
object[""] = "empty string";
// not an exhaustive list
```

ES5 allows you to use [reserved words as properties](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), `x.class = "some string"`, *however* this is not allowed by ES3, so you should probably use brackets `x["class"]` for backwards compatability.

---

Bracket notation can still be used to access valid identifier properties but dot notation is considered cleaner.  Brackets are generally used when you have a variable:

```
object[input.value];  //Retrieves the property named by the value of the input field
```

Functions can also be accessed with brackets:

```
var fn = operation == "tag" ? "getElementsByTagName":"getElementsByClassName";
document[fn](str);
```